# Strip HTML from Exported Excel

Tags: javascript

What I'm doing is allowing people to export there report to excel, it works great except for if they have text, for example an essay question in there and the response has html in it. It shows up fine on the webpage because it styles it but when it is exported to the excel file it will show

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><em><span>There response here</span></em><p>
```

How do I go about removing those html tags before exporting the file to excel? I don't really know what code to post up to show how I'm doing it currently but more of what steps I can take to achieve this.

Edit: There is a report that is created in html on my website, it allows them to export the html report to an excel file but the excel file keeps the html tags from the essay question. How do I remove those tags in javascript before it exports the html report to the excel file?

Comment: Press `Ctrl`+`F` and remove it. Please be a bit more clear!

Comment: Can you post a longer excerpt?  I see that you want to remove the `<p>`, `<em>`, and `<span>` tags, but the context surrounding it.  Or if your website is public and not requiring a signup, a link to the page would work.

Comment: Yeah the website is private to students, I'm trying to rephrase the question its just kind of hard with what I can put on here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
<?php echo strip_tags('<p style="text-align: center;"><em><span>There response here</span></em><p>'); ?>
```

will return:

There response here

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the following

```
htmlResult += results[i].RESPONSES[j].RESPONSE.substring(0,100).replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will strip html tags:

```
function stripTags(html) {
  var temp = document.createElement("div");
  temp.innerHTML = html;
  return temp.textContent || temp.innerText;
}
```

You can pass an element's `innerHTML` to this function, and it will return the contents without any tags.